# How do i use DeviceTree to init GPIO to a set value?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, linux, device-tree

Hello i've got a board connected to my raspberry pi 3 and according to the pin set on boot of the raspberry this shield reboot which is problematic. I need to be able to reset the board and control the pin. I cannot add an EEPROM to use the Raspberry shield system, so i tried to add an overlay to the DT to activate the gpio to an high output at boot but it doesn't work.
My overlay:

```
// Definitions for gpio module 
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";

    fragment@0 {
        target-path = "/";
        __overlay__ {
            test_board: test_board {
                compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&test_board_pin>;
                gpio-controller;
                gpios = <&gpio 27 0>;//GPIO active high is 0
                default-state = "keep";
                non-removable;
                #gpio-cells = <2>;
                status = "okay";
            };
        };
    };
    fragment@1 {
        target = <&gpio>;
        __overlay__ {
            test_board_pin: test_board_pin {
                status = "okay";
                brcm,pins = <27>;
                brcm,pull = <1>;//pull-down
                brcm,function = <1>; // out 
                output-hight;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

I compile it:

```
dtc -W no-unit_address_vs_reg -@ -I dts -O dtb -o test_board.dtbo gpio-test-overlay.dts
```

I add it to the overlay:

```
sudo cp test_board.dtbo /boot/overlays
```

I activate it:

```
dtoverlay=test_board
```

I reboot.
I check that it wok:

```
dtc -I fs /proc/device-tree > look1.txt

gpio@7e200000 {
        compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-gpio";
        gpio-controller;
        #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
        interrupts = <0x2 0x11 0x2 0x12>;
        phandle = <0xc>;
        reg = <0x7e200000 0xb4>;
        #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
        interrupt-controller;

        i2c1 {
            brcm,pins = <0x2 0x3>;
            phandle = <0x13>;
            brcm,function = <0x4>;
        };

        test_board_pin {
            brcm,pins = <0x1b>;
            status = "okay";
            phandle = <0x4b>;
            brcm,pull = <0x1>;
            brcm,function = <0x1>;
            linux,phandle = <0x4b>;
            output-hight;
        };

        spi0_pins {
            brcm,pins = <0x9 0xa 0xb>;
            phandle = <0xd>;
            brcm,function = <0x4>;
        };

        sdhost_pins {
            brcm,pins = <0x30 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35>;
            phandle = <0x17>;
            brcm,function = <0x4>;
        };

        uart1_pins {
            brcm,pins;
            phandle = <0x11>;
            brcm,pull;
            brcm,function;
        };

        i2s {
            brcm,pins = <0x12 0x13 0x14 0x15>;
            phandle = <0xb>;
            brcm,function = <0x4>;
        };
aliases {
    intc = "/soc/interrupt-controller@7e00b200";
    spi2 = "/soc/spi@7e2150c0";
    i2c1 = "/soc/i2c@7e804000";
    i2c_vc = "/soc/i2c@7e205000";
    spi0 = "/soc/spi@7e204000";
    thermal = "/soc/thermal";
    vchiq = "/soc/vchiq";
    sdhost = "/soc/sdhost@7e202000";
    aux = "/soc/aux@0x7e215000";
    gpio = "/soc/gpio@7e200000";
    audio = "/soc/audio";
    dma = "/soc/dma@7e007000";
    soc = "/soc";
    leds = "/leds";
    mmc = "/soc/mmc@7e300000";
    serial1 = "/soc/serial@7e201000";
    i2c_arm = "/soc/i2c@7e804000";
    ethernet = "/soc/usb@7e980000/usb1@1/usbether@1";
    uart0 = "/soc/serial@7e201000";
    fb = "/soc/fb";
    i2c2 = "/soc/i2c@7e805000";
    i2s = "/soc/i2s@7e203000";
    spi1 = "/soc/spi@7e215080";
    usb = "/soc/usb@7e980000";
    i2c0 = "/soc/i2c@7e205000";
    watchdog = "/soc/watchdog@7e100000";
    sound = "/soc/sound";
    mailbox = "/soc/mailbox@7e00b880";
    uart1 = "/soc/serial@7e215040";
    random = "/soc/rng@7e104000";
    i2c = "/soc/i2c@7e804000";
    serial0 = "/soc/serial@7e215040";
};
.......................

test_board {
    gpios = <0xc 0x1b 0x0>;
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";
    gpio-controller;
    status = "okay";
    phandle = <0x4c>;
    #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
    pinctrl-0 = <0x4b>;
    default-state = "keep";
    linux,phandle = <0x4c>;
    non-removable;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
};
```

So the code OVERLAY is well integrated in the DT but the gpio is not exported, and when i export it, i can see that it's not set to output but input.

Can you help me to activate my GPIO?

thanks,

Comment: If I understand your question (which is rather vague) you are **ATTEMPTING** to change GPIO 27. This is **ALREADY** defined in the DTS. You will need to modify the existing.

Comment: That's why i'm doing an overlay, which is loaded over the DT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved my issues more or less. The answer is that the module(driver) doesn't handle very well the IO and all the functionality of the DT(pull up/down). this is what I did:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/{
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";

    // we use pin ctrl and no GPIO ctrl so has to not have a driver claim the GPIO and then not be able to control it normaly
    // see : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/pinctrl-bindings.txt
    // https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/brcm%2Cbcm2835
    // VS: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt
    // driver drivers/pinctrl/bcm/pinctrl-bcm2835.c used by RPI3 doesn't implement the generic "output-low/high" of pinctrl.
    // this mean we cannot set it until boot is complet but we can set a pull-up/down (pinmux-pins not pins)
    // There is no DPI driver module, but we need a platform device node (that doesn't already use pinctrl) to hang the pinctrl
    // reference on - leds will do

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&gpio>;
        __overlay__ {
            my_pins: my_pins {
                brcm,pins = <22 27 23>;
                brcm,pull = <1 2 1>;//no pull on output
                brcm,function = <0 0 0>;//input
            };
        };
    };
    fragment@0 {
        target = <&leds>;
        __overlay__ {
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&my_pins>;
        };
    };
};
```